# Mock Typeorm QueryBuilder

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, mocking, typeorm

I need to test a call like this:

```
    const queryBuilder = getConnection('default')
        .createQueryBuilder(Reading, 'r')
        .where("r.code = :code AND um = 'KWH'", { code: meter.code })
        .andWhere(" measure_date BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date(:endDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')", {
            startDate,
            endDate,
        })
        .andWhere('r.deleted_at IS NULL')
        .orderBy('r.measure_date', 'DESC')
        .addOrderBy('r.reading_type')
        .addOrderBy('r.band', 'ASC');

    const readings = await queryBuilder.getMany();
```

my test:

```
    const fakeSelectQueryBuilder = createStubInstance(typeorm.SelectQueryBuilder);
    fakeSelectQueryBuilder.where.returnsThis();
    fakeSelectQueryBuilder.andWhere.returnsThis();
    fakeSelectQueryBuilder.addOrderBy.returnsThis();
    fakeSelectQueryBuilder.orderBy.returnsThis();
    fakeSelectQueryBuilder.getMany.resolves([]);

    const fakeConnection = createStubInstance(typeorm.Connection);
    fakeConnection.createQueryBuilder.resolves(fakeSelectQueryBuilder);
```

but i receive:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
```

i tried many solutions, but none worked.
any suggestions?

thx to all

Comment: Where does `getConnection` function come from? Please include the code

Comment: it's a typeorm function to select between multiple connections https://typeorm.io/#/connection/working-with-connection-1

Comment: Are you using `jestjs` or `sinonjs`? for mocking?

Comment: i am using sinon, I also updated my question with some (wrong) test

Comment: You are using sinon as stub library and jestjs as your test runner?

Comment: @slideshowp2 exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution I found:

```
const fakeSelectQueryBuilder = sandbox.createStubInstance(typeorm.SelectQueryBuilder);
fakeSelectQueryBuilder.where.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder.andWhere.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder.addOrderBy.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder.orderBy.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder.getMany.resolves([{ plp: 666 }]);

const fakeSelectQueryBuilder2 = sandbox.createStubInstance(typeorm.SelectQueryBuilder);
fakeSelectQueryBuilder2.where.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder2.andWhere.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder2.addOrderBy.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder2.orderBy.returnsThis();
fakeSelectQueryBuilder2.getMany.resolves([{ plp: 999 }]);

const connection = sandbox.createStubInstance(typeorm.Connection);
connection.createQueryBuilder.onFirstCall().callsFake((p): any => {
    return fakeSelectQueryBuilder as any;
});
connection.createQueryBuilder.onSecondCall().callsFake((p): any => {
    return fakeSelectQueryBuilder2 as any;
});

sandbox.stub(typeorm, 'createConnections').resolves(([connection] as unknown) as typeorm.Connection[]);
sandbox.stub(typeorm, 'getConnection').returns(connection as any);
```

note that I have mulitple connections in my app so I stubbed the **typeorm.createConnections** function and multiple buildingManager in tested code so I use **onFirstCall** and **onSecondCall**.